# app runs in background on ios4

Tags: iphone, ios4

I hope to run an app in background on ios4

I know

Apple allows only certain types of apps to run in the background, like navigation and audio and VOIP apps. But even those are limited to only the necessary tasks.

Is it possible I register the app as one kind of  VoIP, Audio or GPS apps to keep it run in background?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "run" an app in the background; you can only run a task in the background. The tasks are

- Continue Playing Audio
- Maintain VoIP Connection
- Update Location (GPS)
- Some Finite Task (such as uploading a file)

I haven't developed for iOS so there might be something I'm missing. Read more at [Executing Code in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). As of iOS 4, developers don't have the ability to implement true multitasking. Correct me if I'm wrong in any of this.

Answer (score 1):

Not in general, no. You could register a VoIP or GPS session and abuse its callbacks for certain tasks, but I doubt the App Store review process would take kindly to it.

What do you need to do in the background that isn't covered by task completion or the audio/VoIP/GPS background modes? it might be possible to use another paradigm and still get the cake.